# Can't exit from comment mode using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: bug, comments, usability, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

While browsing through the questions in a mouse and pointer free environment, if someone accidentally clicks on <kbd>C</kbd> instead of the intended <kbd>V</kbd>, they go to the comment mode on post itself.

Intuitively, if I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>; it should close the comment box and let the user browse question and answers as before, however; the **Escape** key does nothing and the user has to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get out of comment-mode.

> <sub>Not sure if I should mark it as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for adding
>   the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key shortcut from inside of comment box or just
>   report as a bug!</sub>

Comment: For me, the Escape key clears out any text typed in, but the comment box still has focus.